# Stdin , stdout, stderr, how can I get my program to take input from a text file and output to a text file

Tags: c, file, input, output

In a programming competition , they mentioned this:

> " How to answer to the problems?
>   In the problems you are up to solve, you have to read data from a file **.IN**, and write the results in a file **OUT.** "

I am used to the regular way of programming, writing the code in IDE , compiling , then executing it to see what's going on, and it worked, however my answers were refused.

Does anyone know anything about those file.IN and .OUT thing?

I mean, **how can I get my program to take input from a textfile in which I write the dat aI want to give to the program, and make it send the the output to another textfile ?**

**Thanks**

Comment: you have to you library routines to read and write to files or reopen stdin and out as files.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the competition? Can you demonstrate how you implemented input/output?

Comment: @Hogan I did not understand, please clarify.

Comment: @moooeeeep the competition is a Local one, and the main language is in French, if you are still interested , I'll send you the link.

About implementing, well , the usual way , importing stdio and workign the regular way..

Comment: Then you should probably ask the people who refused your submission. This community can not tell you how they want the I/O to happen.

Comment: @moooeeeep I see, can you tell me more, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `stdio.h` in your header files.

In your main function, include the following lines on top.

```
freopen("input.in","r",stdin);
freopen("output.out","w",stdout);
```

In most online programming competitions, input is given through `stdin` and output through `stdout`. However, in this case, you have to read input from a file (.in) and write to a file (.out). freopen takes the stream(stdin, stdout) specified as the third argument to re-open the stream and instead use the file specified.

Edit: Sample code takes input from input.in and writes to output.out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
freopen("input.in","r",stdin);
freopen("output.out","w",stdout);
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d\n",n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Thanks!** 

You've shown me the thread to follow.

What I understand is , that I do not have to make the input functions (scanf..) in my main function , but rather put the data in the input.in?

Same goes with the output functions (printf..) ?

Comment: No. You still need to use the functions scanf,printf in your main function to read/write data from/to the files(.in and .out). scanf uses the stream stdin which is standard input from console and printf uses stdout which is standard output to console. With the rest of the program as it is, the `freopen' commands will redirect the streams from console to your file(s). So, it means that you don't need to give  input from console/terminal. Instead, paste whatever input you want to give in input.in and expect all the output in output.out.

Comment: Magnificient **Thanks !**

How about fscanf and fprintf and FILE *f = NULL;... ? What's the differnece?

Comment: Yes, you can also use FILE pointers and fscanf, fprintf etc in dealing with file input/output. In fact, that is the intended way. However, in programming competitions people use the above method as it is relatively quick to code. It is also useful for debugging purposes even for sites which don't require input/output through files.

Comment: @MukulGupta Thanks for this **Brilliant answer**!